# Javascript string replace one at a time and add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

So I have written a code to replace certain words and generate most likely related terms.

For example : 'st vin st vin' must give me array of
[
'st vin st vin',
'saint vin st vin',
'saint vin saint vin',
'st. vin st vin',
'st. vin st. vin',
]

```
const getRelatedTerms =async searchTerm =>{
  const likeTerms=[
    {good:'st', bad:'saint'},
    {good:'st', bad:'st.'},

    {good:'st.', bad:'saint'},
    {good:'st.', bad:'st'},

    {good:'saint', bad:'st.'},
    {good:'saint', bad:'st'}
  ]
  const arr=[];

for(let i=0; i< likeTerms.length; i++){
  let temp =searchTerm;
  let item = likeTerms[i]; 
   while(temp.includes(item.good)){
      temp = temp.replace(item.good,item.bad);
      arr.push(temp)
    }
}

}
```

I am not sure what's the exact problem here.It throws **CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory** error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has in infinite loop.

As an example of the infinite loop, consider: Your input string is `"st vin"`

You replace `"st"` with `"st."` so your string becomes `"st. vin"`

You then check if `"st. vin"` contains `"st"`, which it does, and you again replace it, now making the string `"st.." vin`. This repeats forever.

There's a few ways to solve this. The easiest is probably to use [`.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) instead.

```js
const getRelatedTerms = searchTerm =>{
  const likeTerms=[
    {good:'st', bad:'saint'},
    {good:'st', bad:'st.'},

    {good:'st.', bad:'saint'},
    {good:'st.', bad:'st'},

    {good:'saint', bad:'st.'},
    {good:'saint', bad:'st'}
  ]
  const arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < likeTerms.length; i++) {
    const item = likeTerms[i];
    arr.push(searchTerm.replaceAll(item.good, item.bad));
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Also note two other errors with your function: You use the `async` function declaration, but your function is synchronous, so you don't need `async`. You also don't return `arr` at the end, which is done in the above code.

**Additional refactoring**

If you want, you can also continue simplifying the function. You can move the declaration of good and bad outside of the function as there doesn't appear to be a need to re-create it every time. And you can change your loop to a map, which returns an array, so you can create the function all in one line. If a function only has one expression, you can remove the wrapping `{` and `}` and remove the `return` statement. This is a benefit of using "fat arrow" functions (`=>`)

```js
const likeTerms = [
  {good:'st', bad:'saint'},
  {good:'st', bad:'st.'},

  {good:'st.', bad:'saint'},
  {good:'st.', bad:'st'},

  {good:'saint', bad:'st.'},
  {good:'saint', bad:'st'}
];

const getRelatedTerms = searchTerm => likeTerms.map(
  ({ good, bad }) => searchTerm.replaceAll(good, bad)
);
```